# Connect local folder to Mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have a local folder, that I know is the `tip` of my repo, but the `.hg` folder is not there, is there a way to "connect" this to a repo without having to clone the entire repo again?

What I did was rather than cloning the repo from bitbucket, I clicked download source as zip. But the zip file does not contain the `.hg` folder, only the source files. So is there a way to connect this local folder back the repo?

I would just run the normal `hg clone ...` again, however this repo is >8GB and that zip took a long time to download!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need the full `.hg` folder to work in a meaningful way with the repository.

The 8 GB zip file you downloaded was just a single revision. The history is likely to be of a similar size. As an example, the OpenOffice repository has a 2.0 GB working copy and a 2.3 GB repository. So that is a 15% overhead for storing 270,000 changesets! In other words: it's normally better to just clone everything instead of checking out a single revision.

When you run `hg clone` you're only downloading the `.hg` folder. Mercurial will then by default checkout the latest revision in the working copy. If it's the checkout step that worries you, then use `hg clone -U` to get a repo without a checkout. Now move the `.hg` folder into your existing folder and run

```
$ hg debugsetparents tip
```

to tell Mercurial that you've manually copied in the files for the `tip` revision.

Comment: And there is no way to get hg to download just the .hg folder?